# Where is the stripes tag library gone?

Tags: java, jsp-tags, stripes

I started to develop a project with the [stripes](http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Home)-framework some days ago. Everything worked fine - but now suddenly, eclipse tells me "Can not find the tag library descriptor for http://stripes.sourceforge.net/stripes.tld" for:

```
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="http://stripes.sourceforge.net/stripes.tld" %>
```

In fact, if i move my browser to this website, sourceforge gives me a 404 error. Where is the taglibrary gone?

**Solution**

As JBNizet described below, you do not need to have access to this uri. Cleaning + rebuilding + deploying just solved everythig. Thanks!

Comment: This URL is just an identifier for a tag library, that you're supposed to have, as a jar file, in your project. What happens when you actually deploy the application and test it? Eclipse is well-known to emit a whole lot of errors which aren't errors at all.

Comment: @JBNizet : I guess the OP's question is correct here, as the `httaccess` for Stripes.tld has been removed from sourceforge.net .

Comment: So what? Do you know how tag libraries work? You don't need to have access to the URI. The URI is just an identifier. It could be `http://someNonExistingSite.com`. What matters is to use the URI that is used inside the .tld file that is inside the jar file containing the tag library.

Comment: @JBNizet You are right. Just worked after cleaning my project. Didn't know it work that way, I'm not a that experienced java-developer though. Sorry for that and thank you very much!

Comment: @JBNizet : Thanks for clearing that up, you could have rebuked me less though. How ever, it was an eye opener and means i need to read up more on how `tld` s work.

Comment: You should add it as an answer and mark that as accepted.